# Symfony+Doctrine: Correct YAML syntax for default value of boolean field

Tags: mysql, symfony1, doctrine, yaml

I am working on the schema for my Symfony app, and I need to set the default value of two boolean fields to false. However, with all the ways I've tried to do it, when the sql gets generated, it comes out with the default keyword, but no default value after it.

my last attempt was:

```
negotiable: 
    type: bool
    default: "false"
complete: 
    type: bool
    default: "false"
```

but I have also tried `default: false`, `default: 'false'`, `default: 0` since false is just an alias for 0 in MySQL, and `default: '0'`

Failing Query:

```
CREATE TABLE dormcode_project (id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT, client_id BIGINT, title VARCHAR(255), briefdesc LONGTEXT, spec LONGTEXT, coder_id BIGINT, paytype VARCHAR(30), negotiable bool DEFAULT , complete bool DEFAULT , created_at DATETIME NOT NULL, updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL, INDEX coder_id_idx (coder_id), INDEX client_id_idx (client_id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) ENGINE = INNODB
```

Notice `negotiable bool DEFAULT , complete bool DEFAULT ,`

The file I've been playing with is the `/config/doctrine/schema.yml` file. I'm kind of new to symfony/doctrine. I think this is the right one, but I guess I could be wrong. I do `symfony cc` between each attempt to insert the sql to make sure that it didn't cache the schema. But it almost seems like its not using the file I've been changing...

Comment: Try (one line): negotiable: { type: boolean, default: false }

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't seem to have made any difference. The exact same, erroneous, sql still gets spit out :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Boolean is a synonym for TINYINT. Use `integer(1)` instead and set your default to 0/1.

Sources:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-overview.html

http://www.symfony-project.org/doctrine/1_2/en/04-Schema-Files

Comment: You should use 'boolean', and let doctrine convert it to the most applicable format of the underlying DB engine.

Comment: @Maerlyn: fair point, although the poster wanted the problem solved for MySQL.

Answer (score 9):

Since I haven't enough points to add a comment, I'll add it as an answer for people finding this through Google and the sorts like myself. I know it's an old question.

In Symfony 2.5 (at least), the correct way of setting a default value in YAML is as follows:

```
negotiable: 
    type: boolean
    options:
        default: 0
complete: 
    type: boolean
    options:
        default: 0
```

Comment: Why is this answer all the way at the bottom.. This is the correct solution. Kudos my friend.

Comment: How strange, I am using the same version (2.5) with this exact syntax, and it still refuses to work :/

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using "bool" you should use "boolean" in schema. Also, default: false should work.

Comment: I changed ti back to `default: false` and changed `bool` to `boolean` but I got the same results

Comment: Show us your updated schema, this works for me: `administrator: { type: boolean, default: false }`.